# How can I make a key pair primary?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I have table that doesn't need a specific field to be the primary key. I could add a auto-increment ID field, but it won't be used at all within database queries...

Can I make a UNIQUE KEY to be primary too?

the UNIQUE KEY consists of two fields paired together:

```
a VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
b VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY uk_ab(a,b)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure (no need for `UNIQUE KEY`):

```
PRIMARY KEY (a, b)
```

Have a look at the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html):

> A `PRIMARY KEY` is a unique index where all key columns must be defined as `NOT NULL`. If they are not explicitly declared as `NOT NULL`, MySQL declares them so implicitly (and silently). A table can have only one `PRIMARY KEY`. The name of a `PRIMARY KEY` is always `PRIMARY`, which thus cannot be used as the name for any other kind of index.

and

> A `PRIMARY KEY` can be a multiple-column index. However, you cannot create a multiple-column index using the `PRIMARY KEY` key attribute in a column specification. Doing so only marks that single column as primary. You must use a separate `PRIMARY KEY(index_col_name, ...)` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would work...

```
PRIMARY KEY uk_ab(a,b)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your table already has a unique constraint, then you need to add primary key (`ALTER TABLE [table_name] ADD CONSTRAINT [constraint_name] PRIMARY KEY (a,b)`), and drop the existing unique constraint. Otherwise, you will have 2 unique indexes on the same columns.
If you create a new table, use `PRIMARY KEY(a,b)` instead of `UNIQUE(a,b)` as proposed by others.